# Django models using conditions

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

My models.py looks like following:

```
class Exercise(models.Model):

    #Field for storing exercise type
    EXERCISE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Best stretch'),
        (2, 'Butterfly reverse'),
        (3, 'Squat row'),
        (4, 'Plank'),
        (5, 'Push up'),
        (6, 'Side plank'),
        (7, 'Squat'),
    )
    exercise_type = models.IntegerField(choices=EXERCISE_TYPE_CHOICES)

    #Field for storing exercise name
    -- Here comes the logic --

    #Field for storing intensity level
    INTENSITY_LEVEL_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Really simple'),
        (2, 'Rather Simple'),
        (3, 'Simple'),
        (4, 'Okay'),
        (5, 'Difficult'),
        (6, 'Rather Difficult'),
        (7, 'Really Difficult'),
    )
    intensity_level = models.IntegerField(choices=INTENSITY_LEVEL_CHOICES)

    #Field for storing video url for a particular exercise
    video_url = models.URLField()

    #Field for storing description of the exercise
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

I want to have a field called '*exercise_name*' for Class Exercise, but in the following way:

- For exercise_type=1 it should be 'Best stretch'
- For exercise_type=1 it should be 'Butterfly reverse' and so on.

How can I achieve this? Or if not this way, is there a better way to do this?

**Bottom line**: My Exercise should have following fields- Type, Name, Description, Video_url

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get string representation based on `exercise_type`, simply use [`get_exercise_type_display()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display). It will returns based on `EXERCISE_TYPE_CHOICES`.

```
ex = Exercise(exercise_type=1, intensity_level=1)
ex.get_exercise_type_display()    # => 'Best stretch'
ex.get_intensity_level_display()  # => 'Really simple'
```

Comment: Do you mean the field will look like following:

    #Field for storing exercise name
    exercise_name=(default=here goes this logic)

Comment: @Nitish, I mean, you don't need to define/declare any additional field. Instead, use `get_FOO_display` which is provided by Django. It's defined by Django if `choices` is set for the field.

Comment: I was thinking it as a field because I wanted to propagate this value till client side. Now my serializer does not have a field exercise_name and so it wouldn't return it. Right?

Comment: @Nitish, You can use [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) without modifying the model calss.